# Determine if SQL UPDATE changed value of column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table with a text column called myTextColumn.  I would like to do something in the PHP application only if an UPDATE changed the value.  I am not using triggers.  Is there a better way to do so other than the following?  Thank you

```
function updateTable($data)
{
    $sql='SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id=:id AND myTextColumn!=:myTextColumn';
    $stmt=db::db()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    if($stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        $sql='UPDATE myTable SET myTextColumn=? WHERE id=?';
        $stmt=db::db()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
}

if(updateTable(array('id'=>123, 'myTextColumn'=>'Some text goes here')))
{
    echo('It Changed');
}
```

Comment: you could check the [affected rowcount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) of the update query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) after your PDO call.  It'll tell you the number of rows affected by your UPDATE.

```
$sql='UPDATE myTable SET myTextColumn=? WHERE id=?';
$stmt=db::db()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 )
{ /* do stuff */ }
```

Comment: I like your approach more.  Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, unless you're waiting for a better one.